# Script to create link to edit Google Form responses stopped working

Tags: forms, function, timestamp, milliseconds

I have been using the script below to create a link that allows responses in individual forms to be easily accessed and edited at later dates. It has been working for over a year and in multiple forms.

On 10/22/22 it stopped working in all the forms it had been working.

Here is the script:

```
function FormURLs() {
var form = FormApp.openById('__FormID__');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var urlCol = 2;
var responses = form.getResponses();
var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
}
for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
}
sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
}
```

Here is the error message:

> 12:23:08 PM   Error
> TypeError: data[j][0].setMilliseconds is not a function
> FormURLs    @ formurls.gs:13

I assume something changed with the way Google Forms is documenting timestamps and now the script doesn't know what to do with the timestamp data. I don't really understand script. I spent a bunch of time finding this script and getting it to work more than a year ago. No recollection of where I found it or what changes (if any) I made to get it to work. I have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: Have you tried dumping `data` in some fashion to see what it contains?

Comment: I have not. I do not know what "dumping data" means, let alone various fashions of doing so. Can you add clarification?

Comment: Well, it looks like you can use [console.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) to show variable values. For example consider running `console.log(data[j][0])` at an appropriate juncture, or perhaps `console.log(data[j])`. You need to see what objects are available in this data structure.

Comment: The script is now working again. I did not make any changes to the script. Apparently google made changes in October that caused the script to stop working, but has made additional changes in the last week or so that are currently permitting the script to function as it had previously functioned.